# Fillbetween an interior bounded by multiple curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, fillbetween

I am using curvilinear coordinates to plot two "TV screens", and want the one in front to occlude the other. I would like to use \fillbetween to paint inside the outer one, but because all the sides are curved I cannot do it with just referencing two curves. Is there a way to \fillbetween multiple curves that bound an interior?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
    
    \newcommand{\xa}{0.1}
    \newcommand{\xb}{0.7}
    \newcommand{\ya}{0.8}
    \newcommand{\yb}{-0.2}
    \newcommand{\za}{1}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \begin{axis}[
            axis equal,
            hide axis
            ]
            
            \renewcommand{\za}{0.5}
            \addplot [name path=A1,domain=0:1, samples=100,draw=black,line width=1pt] ({ ((1-x)*\xa + x*\xb)/sqrt(((1-x)*\xa + x*\xb)^2 + (\ya)^2+ (\za)^2) }, { (\ya)/sqrt(((1-x)*\xa + x*\xb)^2 + (\ya)^2+ (\za)^2) });
            \addplot [name path=A2,domain=0:1, samples=100,draw=black,line width=1pt] ({ ((1-x)*\xa + x*\xb)/sqrt(((1-x)*\xa + x*\xb)^2 + (\yb)^2+ (\za)^2) }, { (\yb)/sqrt(((1-x)*\xa + x*\xb)^2 + (\yb)^2+ (\za)^2) });
            \addplot [name path=A3,domain=0:1, samples=100,draw=black,line width=1pt] ({ (\xa)/sqrt((\xa)^2 + ((1-x)*\ya + x*\yb)^2 + (\za)^2) }, { ((1-x)*\ya + x*\yb)/sqrt((\xa)^2 + ((1-x)*\ya + x*\yb)^2 + (\za)^2) });
            \addplot [name path=A4,domain=0:1, samples=100,draw=black,line width=1pt] ({ (\xb)/sqrt((\xb)^2 + ((1-x)*\ya + x*\yb)^2 + (\za)^2) }, { ((1-x)*\ya + x*\yb)/sqrt((\xb)^2 + ((1-x)*\ya + x*\yb)^2 + (\za)^2) });
            
            
            \renewcommand{\za}{1}
            \addplot [name path=B1,domain=0:1, samples=100,draw=black,line width=1pt] ({ ((1-x)*\xa + x*\xb)/sqrt(((1-x)*\xa + x*\xb)^2 + (\ya)^2+ (\za)^2) }, { (\ya)/sqrt(((1-x)*\xa + x*\xb)^2 + (\ya)^2+ (\za)^2) });
            \addplot [name path=B2,domain=0:1, samples=100,draw=black,line width=1pt] ({ ((1-x)*\xa + x*\xb)/sqrt(((1-x)*\xa + x*\xb)^2 + (\yb)^2+ (\za)^2) }, { (\yb)/sqrt(((1-x)*\xa + x*\xb)^2 + (\yb)^2+ (\za)^2) });
            \addplot [name path=B3,domain=0:1, samples=100,draw=black,line width=1pt] ({ (\xa)/sqrt((\xa)^2 + ((1-x)*\ya + x*\yb)^2 + (\za)^2) }, { ((1-x)*\ya + x*\yb)/sqrt((\xa)^2 + ((1-x)*\ya + x*\yb)^2 + (\za)^2) });
            \addplot [name path=B4,domain=0:1, samples=100,draw=black,line width=1pt] ({ (\xb)/sqrt((\xb)^2 + ((1-x)*\ya + x*\yb)^2 + (\za)^2) }, { ((1-x)*\ya + x*\yb)/sqrt((\xb)^2 + ((1-x)*\ya + x*\yb)^2 + (\za)^2) });
            
            \addplot[green!20] fill between [of = A1 and A2, soft clip = {domain = -1:1}];
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can probably replace the given curves with arcs.  The problem is getting the right starting and ending angles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular `\path` and `\fill` commands in combination with `intersection segments`. But you can only stitch together two paths at a time this way, so you need to go several steps.

If you want the smaller screen show over the larger one, you need to change the order in which you draw them (or use [`background`s](https://tikz.dev/library-backgrounds)).

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\xa}{0.1}
    \newcommand{\xb}{0.7}
    \newcommand{\ya}{0.8}
    \newcommand{\yb}{-0.2}
    \newcommand{\za}{1}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \begin{axis}[
            axis equal,
            hide axis
        ]
            
            \renewcommand{\za}{0.5}
            \addplot[name path=A1, domain=0:1, samples=100, draw=black, line width=1pt] 
                ({ ((1 - x)*\xa + x*\xb)/sqrt(((1 - x)*\xa + x*\xb)^2 + (\ya)^2 + (\za)^2) }, 
                 { (\ya)/sqrt(((1 - x)*\xa + x*\xb)^2 + (\ya)^2 + (\za)^2) });
            \addplot[name path=A2, domain=0:1, samples=100, draw=black, line width=1pt] 
                ({ ((1 - x)*\xa + x*\xb)/sqrt(((1 - x)*\xa + x*\xb)^2 + (\yb)^2 + (\za)^2) }, 
                 { (\yb)/sqrt(((1 - x)*\xa + x*\xb)^2 + (\yb)^2 + (\za)^2) });
            \addplot[name path=A3, domain=0:1, samples=100, draw=black, line width=1pt] 
                ({ (\xa)/sqrt((\xa)^2 + ((1 - x)*\ya + x*\yb)^2 + (\za)^2) }, 
                 { ((1 - x)*\ya + x*\yb)/sqrt((\xa)^2 + ((1 - x)*\ya + x*\yb)^2 + (\za)^2) });
            \addplot[name path=A4, domain=0:1, samples=100, draw=black, line width=1pt] 
                ({ (\xb)/sqrt((\xb)^2 + ((1 - x)*\ya + x*\yb)^2 + (\za)^2) }, 
                 { ((1 - x)*\ya + x*\yb)/sqrt((\xb)^2 + ((1 - x)*\ya + x*\yb)^2 + (\za)^2) });
            
            \renewcommand{\za}{1}
            \addplot[name path=B1, domain=0:1, samples=100, draw=black, line width=1pt] 
                ({ ((1 - x)*\xa + x*\xb)/sqrt(((1 - x)*\xa + x*\xb)^2 + (\ya)^2 + (\za)^2) }, 
                 { (\ya)/sqrt(((1 - x)*\xa + x*\xb)^2 + (\ya)^2+ (\za)^2) });
            \addplot[name path=B2, domain=0:1, samples=100, draw=black, line width=1pt] 
                ({ ((1 - x)*\xa + x*\xb)/sqrt(((1 - x)*\xa + x*\xb)^2 + (\yb)^2 + (\za)^2) }, 
                 { (\yb)/sqrt(((1 - x)*\xa + x*\xb)^2 + (\yb)^2 + (\za)^2) });
            \addplot[name path=B3, domain=0:1, samples=100, draw=black, line width=1pt] 
                ({ (\xa)/sqrt((\xa)^2 + ((1 - x)*\ya + x*\yb)^2 + (\za)^2) }, 
                 { ((1 - x)*\ya + x*\yb)/sqrt((\xa)^2 + ((1 - x)*\ya + x*\yb)^2 + (\za)^2) });
            \addplot[name path=B4, domain=0:1, samples=100, draw=black, line width=1pt] 
                ({ (\xb)/sqrt((\xb)^2 + ((1 - x)*\ya + x*\yb)^2 + (\za)^2) }, 
                 { ((1 - x)*\ya + x*\yb)/sqrt((\xb)^2 + ((1 - x)*\ya + x*\yb)^2 + (\za)^2) });
            
            \path[name path=A13, intersection segments={of=A1 and A3, sequence={L*[reverse] -- R*}}];
            \path[name path=A24, intersection segments={of=A2 and A4, sequence={L* -- R*[reverse]}}];
            \fill[green!20, draw=black, intersection segments={of=A13 and A24, sequence={L* -- R*}}] -- cycle;
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

It might be a good idea to define functions to avoid repetitive code. Also, defining macros with very short names at the global level may conflict with other packages or commands.

Here is a solution that uses previously defined functions, this way avoiding the need to define commands on the global level. The output is the same as above.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \begin{axis}[
            axis equal,
            hide axis,
            /pgf/declare function = {
                xa = 0.1;
                xb = 0.7;
                ya = 0.8;
                yb = -0.2;
                zx = 0.5;
                zy = 1;
                fa(\a,\b,\c,\d) = ((1 - x)*\a + x*\b)/sqrt(((1 - x)*\a + x*\b)^2 + (\c)^2 + (\d)^2);
                fb(\a,\b,\c,\d) = (\a)/sqrt(((1 - x)*\b + x*\c)^2 + (\a)^2 + (\d)^2);
                fc(\a,\b,\c,\d) = (\a)/sqrt((\a)^2 + ((1 - x)*\b + x*\c)^2 + (\d)^2);
                fd(\a,\b,\c,\d) = ((1 - x)*\a + x*\b)/sqrt((\c)^2 + ((1 - x)*\a + x*\b)^2 + (\d)^2);
            }
        ]
            \addplot[name path=A1, domain=0:1, samples=100, draw=black, line width=1pt] 
                ({ fa(xa,xb,ya,zx) }, { fb(ya,xa,xb,zx) });
            \addplot[name path=A2, domain=0:1, samples=100, draw=black, line width=1pt] 
                ({ fa(xa,xb,yb,zx) }, { fb(yb,xa,xb,zx) });
            \addplot[name path=A3, domain=0:1, samples=100, draw=black, line width=1pt] 
                ({ fc(xa,ya,yb,zx) }, { fd(ya,yb,xa,zx) });
            \addplot[name path=A4, domain=0:1, samples=100, draw=black, line width=1pt] 
                ({ fc(xb,ya,yb,zx) }, { fd(ya,yb,xb,zx) });

            \addplot[name path=B1, domain=0:1, samples=100, draw=black, line width=1pt] 
                ({ fa(xa,xb,ya,zy) }, { fb(ya,xa,xb,zy) });
            \addplot[name path=B2, domain=0:1, samples=100, draw=black, line width=1pt] 
                ({ fa(xa,xb,yb,zy) }, { fb(yb,xa,xb,zy) });
            \addplot[name path=B3, domain=0:1, samples=100, draw=black, line width=1pt] 
                ({ fc(xa,ya,yb,zy) }, { fd(ya,yb,xa,zy) });
            \addplot[name path=B4, domain=0:1, samples=100, draw=black, line width=1pt] 
                ({ fc(xb,ya,yb,zy) }, { fd(ya,yb,xb,zy) });
            
            \path[name path=A13, intersection segments={of=A1 and A3, sequence={L*[reverse] -- R*}}];
            \path[name path=A24, intersection segments={of=A2 and A4, sequence={L* -- R*[reverse]}}];
            \fill[green!20, draw=black, intersection segments={of=A13 and A24, sequence={L* -- R*}}] -- cycle;
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, very thorough.